# How to use angular2_material dart

Tags: dart, angular-dart

Does anyone know of a site where **angular2_material Dart** example can be found?

I know it is its alpha state but it would be nice to be able to experiment with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Angular [GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/modules/examples/src/material/button)   repo contains some examples.
Seems they are built so that the Dart code can automatically generated but I haven't done that myself yet.
Seems there are only very few Angular2 material elements available yet.

Comment: Thanks. I did see the repo, but was hoping something more substantial was out there. Appreciate the help GZ.

Comment: I know, but it seems there isn't more yet. It seems they just tried to port some very simple elements to Angular2. I guess Angular2 is still too much in flux to make porting work worthwile.